# Install Azure Functions version 1

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2017, azure-functions

I am required to write an Azure Function, with HTTP triggers.  My problem is, when I choose Azure Functions template in Visual Studio 2017, it just creates an empty project with two files, host.json and local.setting.json, which makes me believe that I have version 2 of the Azure Functions installed.

When I try and compile this version of the Azure Functions I have installed, I get a message saying that I need .Net Frameworik 4.7.2 installed, and I cannot install this framework version on my Windows 10 version.

How can I downgrade or install the Azure Functions version 1?

My Environment:

1. Windows 10 (Build 10240)
2. Visual Studio 2017 Professional (version 15.5.4)

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to update your Visual Studio 2017 to 15.8.1 if possible.

15.5.4 seems too old and doesn't work with latest [Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/blob/master/VS-AzureTools-ReleaseNotes.md#release-notes---azure-functions-and-web-jobs-tools).

Many templates support in latest Azure function extension.

[image]

Comment: Updating Visual Studio now to version 15.8.1, will see if this makes a difference

Answer (score 1):

While you are creating a new Azure Functions project in Visual Studio, you get asked which version (v1 or v2) you want. The structure of the project (the two files you mention) are the same for both versions.

The difference is that v1 is targeting full .NET Framework 4.6+, while v2 is targeting .NET Standard 2.x.

I've just tried with VS 15.8 and v1 project template is targeting 4.6.1 by default, so this version should be enough.

Comment: I do not get asked which version I want to use?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create function app from command line using `func` command. To install CLI I recommend use of chocolatey and simply type `choco install azure-functions-core-tools`.